# prolog recursion explanation for a code snippet

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have some `parent/2` facts like `parent(Parent, Child)` and with them I want to find predecessor relation between two object or variable (like `predecessor(Predecessor,Successor)`). The code snippet is:

```
predecessor(X,Z):-
    parent(X,Z).
predecessor(X,Z):-
    parent(X,Y),
    predecessor(Y,Z).
```

Some facts or relations are:

```
parent(tom,bob).
parent(pam,bob).
parent(tom,liz).
parent(tom,carl).
parent(bob,ann).
parent(bob,pat).
parent(pat,jim).
```

My question is which predecessor clause will run first and how this recursion will terminate for the call `predecessor(tom,jim)`.

Comment: This looks like homework copied *almost* verbatim. Have you tried to find answers to these questions yourself?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hello. Actually this is literally from a book named "prolog programming for Artificial Intelligence". There's no explanation for this code snippet about how they work. I can upload a screenshot of the book's page if you want. I just want an explanation of how this code snippet works for the call "predecessor(tom,jim)".

Comment: @AsashanAlamSojib: no need to. Was only asking. Posting homework questions is allowed btw, but it is appreciated if in that case you show some effort.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `trace` to see what the code does on `predecessor(tom, jim)`? The answer to which clause runs "fast" seems simply enough to be the first clause since it does the same as the second, less the recursion.

Comment: @lurker sorry for typo. I wanted to know which clause will run first for the call "predecessor(tom, jim)".

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib the first clause always runs first. Prolog checks clauses heads from first to last in the listing. When the recursive call to `predecessor/2` is made, it then also starts back at the first clause head for execution.